# Ruby 1.8, Getting all Hash values related to a specific key

Tags: ruby, csv, hash

I have the following code which takes a CSV file and feed it into a hash.  Here I want to list all the names of songs for a specific genre. Like, all the "Western" songs.  This code only gives me one song for a specific genre.  Does anyone have suggestions on how I can get it to show all the Western songs (for example)

```
def self.musicGenre()
  puts "Ballad,Blues,Bluegrass,Popular,Western"
  require 'csv'
  @musicGenreHash={} #create the hash for musicName, blank
  CSV.foreach('musiclist.txt')do |row| 
    name,genre,composer,location = row 
    @musicGenreHash[genre]=name
  end

    def self.genre(songGenreChoice)
      @musicGenreHash[songGenreChoice]
    end

  puts "Please type in the genre of your choice:"
    songGenreChoice=gets.chomp

    puts "Thesearethesongsavailable in the#{songGenreChoice} genre:"+genre("#{songGenreChoice}").inspect
 end #musicGenre
```

Comment: Going to need more context, where are you defining this method? presumably inside of a ruby class? Could you update your question to include your entire class definition as well as what you're trying to do with that class?

Comment: Hi Andrew,  Here is the entire code.  Yes this is inside a class.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing only one value against a genre.  You need to modify your code so that values in the hash are array, and you collect the names of all songs belonging to particular genre in that array.

Change

```
@musicGenreHash[genre]=name
```

to

```
@musicGenreHash[genre] = (@musicGenreHash[genre] || []) << name
```

Comment: Hi Wand Maker,  Thanks for your help. Unfortunately i received the error "    undefined local variable or method `musicGenreHash'".  I'm supposing that I can't use the hash as a variable too.

Comment: Works fine for me with whatever code you have shared.  You may have some other errors in your original code.  The essence of my answer is to use Array as value in the hash, as long as you do that, you can store multiple songs against a genre name in the hash